# React project in a docker container returns net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a React project which is Dockerized along with asp.net core 6.0 app and SQL Server database. the production yaml file is as below:

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  # UI Container spec. note that 'ui' is the name of the container internally (also 'container_name')
  ui:
    container_name: myapp-ui-prod
    image: myapp-ui-prod
    env_file: ./UI/.env
    build:
      context: ./UI
      dockerfile: DockerFile_UI.prod    
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    networks:
      - psnetwork
    links:
      - api

  # Database Container spec.
  sql:
    container_name: myapp-sql
    image: myapp-sql
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: 'Pa55w0rd'
    build:
      context: ./DockerDB
      dockerfile: DockerFile_SQL
    ports:
      - 1633:1433 # Map 1433 from inside the container to 1633 host to avoid port conflict with local install
    networks:
      - psnetwork
    
  # API container spec.
  api:
    container_name: myapp-api
    image: myapp-api
    build:
      context: ./Api
      dockerfile: DockerFile_API
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:5555
    ports:
        - "5555:5555"
    networks:
      - psnetwork
    links:
      - sql
networks:
  psnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

The React project can ping api container successfully while when I call the api graphql endpoint through http it gives `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error. The nginx configuration file is as below:

```
upstream api_backend {
    server api:5555;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  # server_name example.com;
  location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://api/api;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}



# server {
 
# }
```

And the ApolloClient configuration in React app is:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL+ '/api/graphql',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

the `.env` file contents is:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL="http://api:5555"
```

The project works when I use localhost:5555 IP address.

Comment: The React application runs in the end user's browser, which is outside of Docker.  A host name `api` doesn't mean anything to it.

Comment: Alright, how can I set it if I want to publish it